# Apache2 simplest redirect not working anymore

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, http, redirect, https

I am new at Server configurations, and I´m having a probably weird problem.

I set up a webserver with success, even having a working redirect from http to https.
And now, without knowingly changing anything the redirect stopped working.

I broke the relevant configuration part down to this:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/myServername.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myServername
   Redirect permanent / https://myServername/
</VirtualHost>
```

First, if I typed "myServername" in my Browser i came out to "https://myServername/" as I intended to to. Now I see the index page of my server with normal http access. How can that be?

I use  Apache/2.4.10 on a Debian system.

Regards, 
Tobi

Comment: You only mention sites-available. Is the site enabled?

Comment: yes it is. And other entries in the same config file are working, too.

Comment: Your comment helped anyway, by checking if the site is enabled I realised the 000-default file was enabled, too. It was specified on port 80, too. Looks like that somehow apache2 started using this entry sometime. Thank you, problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the 000-default file was enabled, too. And it was specified on port 80, too. Looks like that somehow apache2 started using this entry sometime. Thank you, problem is solved :)